# How does one decide if the meat is halal if he doesn't witness the slaughter?

Tags: halal-haram, halal-certification

Anyone can make a claim that a food is halaal. There are food and imported meat that are certified halaal. But, these are imported from Muslim minority countries (like imported chicken from Brazil). So is such a certification sufficient? If not, what are the other requirements that are necessary to establish the halal status of a food, if one doesn't witness the slaughter?

Comment: struggling with this question my self.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't really a way especially is the blood is drained properly. If something is labelled as halal and you eat it, then eat it with the intention that it is halal. If it turns out that the meat was infact haram, then you are not at fault as Allah knows you could only rely on the label and what you had been told. Therefore the one selling the product to you will be at fault as they lied about the product to you. However if you have doubt for whatever reason then it is best to avoid that particular product and purchase the product from another supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam o Allaikum.

If the meat that you eat is from Halal animal and also it is written on it as well then surely it is Halal. Even if the food is Halal then still you won't be considered guilty because you did not know it. Islam does not punish you for the activity that you didn't know or committed unintentionally.

> Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) once said; **"The reward of deeds depends upon
> the intention and every person will get the reward according to what
> he has intended."** (Sahih Bukhari, Kitab-ul-Imaan, Hadith No. 53)

This hadith itself clears many misconceptions that we mostly have.

Comment: I think "*Even if the food is Halal …*" should be "*Even if the food is **not** Halal*", but it's a trivial correction, so I'm not able to do it myself.